# Google Cloud SQL: Can I change machine type with zero downtime?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We need to change our Google cloud SQL instance from db-g1-small to db-n1-standard-1. Can I change it with zero downtime?

Edit 1

I think I found the answer. It seems that it will take a few seconds of downtime.

> You can change an instance's tier at any time, with just a few seconds
>   of downtime.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing

Edit 2

I tried it on our dev env. The downtime was about 10 sec.

```
while true; date; do curl https://api.xxx.com/v1/items; echo ""; sleep 1s; done

2016/8/29 16:24:50 JST
{"OK"}
2016/8/29 16:24:51 JST
Error
2016/8/29 16:25:01 JST
{"OK"}
```

Answer (score 10):

The note about changing tier in a few seconds is under the First Generation section of that page.

For a Second Generation instance, it may take several minutes.